# gui and main() method

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, program-entry-point

I am currently creating a `mancala-game` in Java. This is what I have so far:

```
package mancala;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Game  {

    private JLabel start;
    private JButton startBtn;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JFrame frame;

    public Game(){
        createForm();
        addButtons();

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void createForm() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Mancala");
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void addButtons() {
        startBtn = new JButton("Start");
    }
}
```

This throws the following error:

```
Error: Main method not found in class mancala.Game, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application
```

But when I add the `main-method` it's still broken, what steps do I have to take to make this work?

Comment: is that the only class you have?

Comment: what do you mean _its still broken_? What error do you see?

Comment: so far yes, its my first java gui so playing around to see how it works. and when i add the main method nothing shows on screen. do i need to call a class from main()?

Comment: Show the variant with a `main(String[])` method..

Answer (score 2):

Your current class is nothing that can be executed. In order to create a new instance of class Game you'll need an additional class. Try to think of the Game-Class as a blueprint, that has to be "used" (by another class).

In your new class you'll have to call the constructor of the Game-class in order to be able to work with it. An example of the new class:

```
package mancala;

public class RunGame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Game game = new Game();
        // Now you can do funky stuff with your generated Instance :)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In java you need to have a class which contains a main method to run. The main method is the first thing to run, and is where you can call other methods from. Your class Game has the constructor method Game(). To call this method from your main method, you should put the following in your main method:

```
new Game();
```

Answer (score 0):

Swing applications that embed JavaFX code require the main() method.

https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/get_started/hello_world.html

this link might be helpful for you to explain this question.